# Spring-ws client side programming

Tags: spring-ws

I want to consume a web service of which I have the wsdl. I am using spring-ws and want to use marshalling/unmarshalling (jaxb) to convert xml to java and vice versa. How can I get the jaxb classes from the wsdl. Do I need access to xsd which in this case I don't have. Can I use a tool like trang to do the work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look here http://blog.dawouds.com/2008/09/maven-2-wsdl-to-java-using-jaxb.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use the tool Apache CXF to create a Web-service client in Java from the WSDL. Follow the official page: http://cxf.apache.org/docs/developing-a-consumer.html